# shiny renderGvis object output not found

Tags: shiny, output, render, dashboard, ggvis

I can't bring a minimal example since it works for one code but not for this one I am asking about. I try to explain the structure of the code because I am pretty sure that someone can help me.

I have the usual Server.R file with

```
Server <- function(input, output, session) {
source("ChartServer.R")
}
```

where source("ChartServer.R"):

```
output$ChartPlotOutput <- renderGvis({

gvisChart <- CREATES A CHART

  return(gvisChart)
})
```

and the ui.R file which is a dasboardpage:

```
source("servicefunctions.R")


source("dashboardBody.R")
source("dashboardHeader.R")
source("dashboardSidebar.R")


dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader,
  dashboardSidebar,
  dashboardBody
  )
```

I have three tab Items of which two are working fine. However one tries to render a plot which is not working (the one mentioned in the server.R file above)

```
source("ChartUI.R")    
aboutTab2 <- tabItem(tabName = "about2",
                            fluidPage(
                              fluidRow(
                                tabBox(id = "PChartUI", width = 7, 
                                       tabPanel(title = 'Prices', PChartUI)
                                ))))
```

source("ChartUI.R"):

```
PChartUI <- tagList(
  htmlOutput("ChartPlotOutput"),
  imageOutput("ChartPlotWidthPlaceholder",width = '100%', height = '50px'))
```

when I try to run this app i always get the error:

```
Error in output$ChartPlotOutput <- renderGvis({ : 
  object 'output' not found
```

As mentioned I already worked with a similar structure that worked but here I can't find what I did wrong.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try adding `local=TRUE` and `$value` when you call source. `source("ChartServer.R", local=TRUE)$value`

Comment: Thanks a lot. local = TRUE works fine.